# Flex box formatting issue

Tags: html, css

I am not able to make my flex box content fill the whole box with sufficient spacing between each content. Here are my codes and image. How can I fix this issue? I have tried using line height and even break but nothing is working. The issue is that items in a single box are not using up the full height of the box.

```css
.parent-box{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.child-box{
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid green;
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    margin: 20px 50px;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    width: 330px;
    height: 450px; /*also used auto but it's not working*/
    align-items: stretch;
}

.cta{
    background-color: hsl(213.4,78.8%,50%); 
    color: hsl(0,0%,100%); 
    padding: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.cta-link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">    
                    <div class="child-box">
                        <h3>Main Header</h3>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h3>PHP is a language</h3>
                        <a class="cta-link" href="#"><h2 class="cta">Choose Now</h2></a>
                    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Flex box issue]

Comment: It doesn't answer it, the issue I am facing is about items in a single box, not the formatting of items in multiple boxes. The items in my box are not using up the full height of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add enough spacing to your flexbox content you can use `gap` on the flex container, in your case :

```
.child-box{
  gap: 8px;
}
```

In order to fill up the entire box, you can use `flex` on a flex item for it to take all the remaining space of the flex container, in your case:

```
h3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

If you want your flex container to take up all the space, (Meaning `child-box`), you need to use `height: 100%` which does not make sense here as you dont have any specified height on your top level container.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make your content fill the entire box vertically, I don't see why height: auto isn't working. I deleted height completely and it seems to work fine

```css
.parent-box{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.child-box{
    background-color: white; 
    border: 1px solid green;
    /*flex-grow: 1;*/
    margin: 20px 50px;
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 330px;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.cta{
    background-color: hsl(213.4,78.8%,50%); 
    color: hsl(0,0%,100%); 
    padding: 20px; 
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.cta-link{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-box">    
                    <div class="child-box">
                        <h3>Main Header</h3>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h4>PHP is a language</h4>
                        <h3>PHP is a language</h3>
                        <a class="cta-link" href="#"><h2 class="cta">Choose Now</h2></a>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When height is set to auto, the box shrinks to a very small size which is not the desired result. How can there be around 5px spacing between the items? This will most likely increase the box height automatically. Box height can either be specified or auto, the desired result is to have vertical space between the items

Comment: Which box are you talking about shrinking to a very small size? The child box or the blue one?

Comment: I was referring to the spaces between the items in the child-box. The working solution is below.